# Why I can't override handleMessage method when I initialize a Handler object?

Tags: java

- It should be like this :

  ```
  Handler handler = new Handler() {  
      @Override  
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {  
          super.handleMessage(msg);  
      }  
  };
  ```
- However,in my IDE,it must be overrided like this:

  ```
      Handler handler = new Handler() {

      @Override
      public void close() {

      }

      @Override
      public void flush() {

      }

      @Override
      public void publish(LogRecord logRecord) {

      }
  };
  ```

And it seems that the Handler object here doesn't support such method called "handleMessage".

What should I do?

Comment: have you tried manually ovveriding handleMessage()? I guess the other 3 methods are automatically created by your IDE because you have to implement them but try to write the override manually

Comment: Also be sure that you imported the right Handler. There's a `Handler` in java which has a method `handleMessage()` and you'll have to `import javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler;` in order to use that!

Comment: Could you write the entire import for Handler, it seems like you are implementing java.util.logging.Handler and you want to implement something like javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler

Comment: check your import of Handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a name conflict between different `Handler` classes.

The first `Handler` you mention seems to be a `javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler` [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/Handler.html) or a `android.os.Handler` [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), both of which have a `handleMessage` method to override.

The second `Handler` seems like it is a `java.util.logging.Handler` [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html) that has the methods you mention